# Bash array - pick selected members(slice) and put them into a new variable

Tags: arrays, bash, variables

```
array1=$(command1)

echo ${array1[@]}
292102 Mon May 12 22:35:12 2014 289368 Mon May 12 14:18:47 2014 280508 Mon May 12 13:44:12 2014 293976 Mon May 12 12:04:08 2014 293227 Mon May 12 03:07:28 2014 291745 Mon May 12 01:46:23 2014
```

I need to run loop where I set variable as for the first loop:

```
${TN}=292102
${LastUpdated}="Mon May 12 22:35:12 2014"
```

so it should be something like:

```
${TN}=${array1[0]}
${LastUpdated}="${array1[1]}${array1[2]}${array1[3]}${array1[4]}${array1[5]}"
```

Number of array members will change after each $(command1)

How can I program some loop that will set variables according to freshly generated array of n members?

EDIT:
Just to clarify as my question was marked unclear, I needed to slice the array to set up variables and join some slices together to make up a variable as date value eg. "Mon May 12 22:35:12 2014", I was not able to describe it the proper way then as I haven't heard of array slicing before that.

Comment: Does `command1` write its output to multiple lines?

Comment: No it does not, it's one line, at least wc -l says so, I can make it multiple lines by running: for i in ${array1[@]}; do echo $i; done

Comment: I though perhaps `292102 Mon May 12 22:35:12 2014` was one line, `289368 Mon May 12 14:18:47 2014` the next, and so on. If so, you could use `while read TN LastUpdated; do ...; done < command1`.

Comment: What if you use something like `echo ${array1[@]} | cut -d" " -f $a-$b`? You can start with `a=1` and `b=6` and increase `a` and `b` by 6 every time you loop.

Comment: Forget about my comment. Array slicing is the thing to to!

Comment: I tried to change a subject to make it clearer what I wanted, however solution has been found already so it may stay closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using array slicing:

```
i=0;
while [ $i -lt $((${#array1[@]}/6)) ]; do
     TN=${array1[i*6]}
     LastUpdated="${array1[@]:i*6+1:5}"
     #Do something with TN & LastUpdated here...
     ((i++))
done
```

Comment: Thanks, that is better code that I could have expected, very simple a works like a charm! Now I will be trying to learn how it works actually ;) Thanks a lot again!